# Triple integral basic

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Need some help on how to think about this question:

$$\iiint_K(x^2+y^2)dxdydz$$

$$0\leq x^2 + y^2 \leq z^2\\
0\leq z \leq 1$$

I have been using spherical solution but does not really get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps cylindrical coordinates are better to use here. Then $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, and the surface is easily parameterised (it's a cone):

$$I=\int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \cdot \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^zr^3dr \right)dz=\frac{\pi}{10}$$